# IIS 7 throwing 500 errors for static content

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7

I have configured an app pool with an integrated pipeline and  .Net 4 framework.  I am using Asp.Net MVC 3 to present my site...

My controllers and views are presenting properly, but references to my static content are all returning sporadic 500 errors from IIS.

For example:  A direct request to `/content/style.css` returns a 500 error.  The detailed error summary message indicates the handler in use is the "StaticFile" and the error code is "0x80070070"

I have granted the 'Everyone' user read access to my /content folder and all child objects.  I have granted the 'Everyone' user full control over my App_Data folder that contains my SqlCompact database.

Any ideas what could be causing my web service to throw these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with this configuration turned out to be read-write access to the contents App_Data folder.  SqlCompact generated a SDF file that needed to be marked as accessible to the web process.  Once that was available, IIS started responding properly.